# Welchen grammatischen Zweck dient hier "der": «als der er abgefahren war»

Tags: sentence-structure

Von Der Zauberberg von Thomas Mann:

> Seine Meinung vielmehr war gewesen, sie rasch abzutun, weil sie
>   abgetan werden mußte, ganz als derselbe zurückzukehren, als **der** er
>   abgefahren war, und sein Leben genau dort wieder aufzunehmen, wo er es
>   für einen Augenblick hatte liegenlassen müssen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das Wort »der« ist an dieser Stelle ein Relativpronomen im Nominativ singular, maskulin und kann durch »welcher« ersetzt werden:

> ... ganz als *derselbe* zurückzukehren, als ***der*** er abgefahren war, ...
>   ... ganz als *derselbe* zurückzukehren, als ***welcher*** er abgefahren war, ...

Die Kombinationen *»derselbe, der«* und *»derselbe, welcher«* findet man recht häufig:

> Das ist *derselbe* Mann, ***der*** mir meine Handtasche geklaut hat.
>   Das ist *derselbe* Mann, ***welcher*** mir meine Handtasche geklaut hat.

Auch zusammen mit *»als«* (in diesem Beispiel im Akkusativ):

> Auch wenn ihr euch von ihm abgekehrt habt: Für mich ist Kurt noch immer *derselbe* liebevolle Mensch, als ***den/welchen*** ich ihn kennengelernt habe.

Comment: ahh, jetzt macht es Sinn!

Comment: so ist es("der") Dativ

Comment: @user135711: Was meinst du mit »Dativ«? Das einzige Wort, das in meinen Beispielen im Dativ steht, ist *»ihm«* im Satz *»Auch wenn ihr euch von **ihm** abgekehrt habt«*. Alles andere steht im Nominativ oder Akkusativ.

Comment: Stimmt so. Wenn "der" eine situtation verträte, von der er gereist ist, würde es im Akkusativ, nicht Dativ sein. Lassen Sie mich denken auf dieser verdoppelten nominitive "der er"