# Welchem ​Zweck dient »der« in »Ja, ich bin der Martin«?

Tags: grammar-identification, person-names

> Ja, ich bin der Martin.

Welchem Zweck dient *der* hier?

Ich denke, dass es mit  [Welchen grammatischen Zweck dient hier "der": «als der er abgefahren war»](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/37590) verbunden ist, aber ein Canoo.net-Link oder grammatischer Name würden mir helfen, es selbst zu begreifen.

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3937*

Comment: The same question in English: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3937/why-is-there-a-definite-article-precedent-to-a-name/3941#3941

Comment: @piedpiper I wasn't sure if this was the same situation as that grammatical structure applied to relative pronoun when I first saw it, not adjective like modifiers. https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33476/why-is-der-used-in-this-excerpt-instead-of-er

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is there a definite article precedent to a name?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3937/why-is-there-a-definite-article-precedent-to-a-name)

Comment: @Uwe Nach [diesem Meta-Post](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-with-duplicate-questions-in-another-language) sollen gleiche Fragen, allerdings in verschiedenen Sprachen, nicht als Duplikate behandelt werden.

Comment: This is just a regional thing, isn't it? Or, it sounds like baby-talk to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Ich denke, dass es [mit] "Welchen grammatischen Zweck dient hier “der”: «als der er abgefahren war»" verbunden ist [...]

In der verlinkten Frage hat "der" die Rolle eines [Relativpronomen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativpronomen).

> Ja, ich bin der Martin.

Hier ist es ein [proprialer Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artikel_(Wortart)#Proprialer_Artikel) (und damit optional).

Weiter heißt es bei Wikipedia:

> Personennamen werden laut Lehrbuch nur dann mit Artikel gebraucht, wenn vor dem Namen ein Adjektiv steht: *der hübsche Hans, die kluge Petra*. Im oberdeutschen Sprachraum ist es jedoch üblich, Namen (außer in der Anrede), mit dem bestimmten Artikel zu verwenden.

Martin möchte unter Umständen auch nur betonen, dass er genau der Martin ist, um den es geht (bezieht sich auf eine vorangegangen Unterhaltung in der er mit der anderen Person nicht *direkt* gesprochen hat).

Umgangssprachlich ist das vollkommen korrekt:

> Ja, ich bin Martin.

Answer (score 5):

Auf [dem Atlas der deutschen Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/artikelvorname/) finden sich Karten, die die regionale Verbreitung der Form *Artikel+Vorname* zeigen: Sie ist im Süden und in der Mitte des deutschen Sprachraumes allgemein verbreitet und nur im Norden eher unbekannt.

In dem entsprechenden Lied ("Ich bin der Martin" von Dieter Krebs) erzeugt die nicht-standardkonforme Verwendung des Artikels zusammen mit der dialektal geprägten Aussprache einen parodistischen Effekt.